# Rational and irrational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Consider $x$ a rational number. Let $\epsilon \geq 0$ be the minimal value  such that $x + \epsilon$ is irrational, and let also $\gamma > 0$ be the minimal value such that $x+\gamma$ is rational. How to compute $\gamma/\epsilon$?

Comment: If you need to reformulate this question, do so and let Michael know, since he answered your original question and the edit might render his answer useless.

Comment: There is no minimal value $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply: $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}(x+\varepsilon)=x$, and it was given that $x$ is irrational.

**Update after drastic revision of the question:** There are no such minimal values, in either of the two cases.  If some positive number $x+\varepsilon$ is irrational, then $x+\varepsilon$ is not the minimal value for which that holds, because $x+\dfrac\varepsilon2$ is also irrational.  To prove this, suppose it were rational.  Then $x+\dfrac\varepsilon2 = \dfrac m n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$.  It follows that $\dfrac\varepsilon2=\dfrac m n - x$ and so $\dfrac\varepsilon2$, being a difference between two rational numbers, is rational. And therefore so is $\varepsilon$, so $x+\varepsilon$ must be rational, and we have a contradiction.

It's even simpler if $x+\gamma$ is rational.  Since $x$ is rational, and $x+\gamma$ is rational, we have $\gamma = \left(x+\gamma\right)-x$, a difference of two rational numbers, which is therefore rational.  Since $\gamma$ is thus proved to be rational, so is $\gamma/2$, and then so is $x+\gamma/2$.

So in either of the two cases, every instance fails to be minimal; there's always a smaller one.  There are no such minimal numbers $\gamma$ and $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

$\epsilon$ doesn't exist! And even if it did, $\gamma$ wouldn't exist!

> **Theorem**: If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $a<b$, then there exists a rational number $c$ such that $a<c<b$ and there exists an irrational number $d$ such that $a<d<b$.